# How can i use gtk3 and opengl together?

Tags: python, opengl, gtk3

I have been looking into how to mix gtk3 and opengl, in gtk2 you could use gtkglext but this is not packaged any where meaning any software developed would not end up in software repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to piece this together seems to work quite well tested on two laptops on ubuntu 13.04, posting here incase i ever need it in the future :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# [SNIPPET_NAME: gtk3 opengl example]
# [SNIPPET_CATEGORIES: opengl]
# [SNIPPET_TAGS: opengl, gtk3]
# [SNIPPET_DESCRIPTION: using gtk3 library lets draw using opengl]
# [SNIPPET_AUTHOR: Oliver Marks ]
# [SNIPPET_LICENSE: GPL]

import sys
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL import GLX
from OpenGL.raw._GLX import struct__XDisplay
from OpenGL import GL
from ctypes import *

import Xlib
from Xlib.display import Display
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkX11, Gdk


class gtkgl:
    """ these method do not seem to exist in python x11 library lets exploit the c methods """
    xlib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libX11.so')
    xlib.XOpenDisplay.argtypes = [c_char_p]
    xlib.XOpenDisplay.restype = POINTER(struct__XDisplay)
    xdisplay = xlib.XOpenDisplay("")
    display = Xlib.display.Display()
    attrs = []

    xwindow_id = None
    width = height = 200

    def __init__(self):
        """ lets setup are opengl settings and create the context for our window """
        self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_RGBA, True)
        self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_RED_SIZE, 1)
        self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1)
        self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1)
        self.add_attribute(GLX.GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, 0)

        xvinfo = GLX.glXChooseVisual(self.xdisplay, self.display.get_default_screen(), self.get_attributes())
        configs = GLX.glXChooseFBConfig(self.xdisplay, 0, None, byref(c_int()))
        self.context = GLX.glXCreateContext(self.xdisplay, xvinfo, None, True)

    def add_attribute(self, setting, value):
        """just to nicely add opengl parameters"""
        self.attrs.append(setting)
        self.attrs.append(value)

    def get_attributes(self):
        """ return our parameters in the expected structure"""
        attrs = self.attrs + [0, 0]
        return (c_int * len(attrs))(*attrs)

    def configure(self, wid):
        """  """
        self.xwindow_id = GdkX11.X11Window.get_xid(wid)
        if(not GLX.glXMakeCurrent(self.xdisplay, self.xwindow_id, self.context)):
            print 'failed'
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

    def draw_start(self):
        """make cairo context current for drawing"""
        if(not GLX.glXMakeCurrent(self.xdisplay, self.xwindow_id, self.context)):
            print "failed"

    def draw_finish(self):
        """swap buffer when we have finished drawing"""
        GLX.glXSwapBuffers(self.xdisplay, self.xwindow_id)

    def test(self):
        """Test method to draw something so we can make sure opengl is working and we can see something"""
        self.draw_start()

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        glIndexi(0)
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex2i(0, 1)
        glIndexi(0)
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex2i(-1, -1)
        glIndexi(0)
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex2i(1, -1)
        glEnd()

        self.draw_finish()


class gui():
    glwrap = gtkgl()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.realize()
        self.window.resize(self.glwrap.width, self.glwrap.height)
        self.window.set_resizable(True)
        self.window.set_reallocate_redraws(True)
        self.window.set_title("GTK3 with opengl")
        self.window.connect('delete_event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.window.connect('destroy', lambda quit: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.drawing_area.connect('configure_event', self.on_configure_event)
        self.drawing_area.connect('draw', self.on_draw)
        self.drawing_area.set_double_buffered(False)
        self.drawing_area.set_size_request(self.glwrap.width, self.glwrap.height)

        self.window.add(self.drawing_area)
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_configure_event(self, widget, event):
        self.glwrap.configure(widget.get_window())
        return True

    def on_draw(self, widget, context):
        self.glwrap.test()


def main():
    g = gui()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always pack gtkglext yourself. Also, you might want to use [Clutter](https://wiki.gnome.org/Clutter) for OpenGl interaction inside a Gtk+ widgets hierarchy.

Comment: will leave gtkglext packaging to some one more experienced, will look into the clutter option though thanks.

Comment: +Oly by packaging I meant use static linking inside you application, or a internal library, not actual distro package. But sure, Clutter is the preferred way